# Update from High Sierra

Tags: software-update

I'm new to iMac and have tried setting up but I can't download a lot of apps due to needing latest software. I'm on high Sierra and when I try to update nothing happens. Any help or advice?

- Mac OS high Sierra.10.13.6 (17G66)
- iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)

  - 2.5 GHz Intel Core
  - 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
  - AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB

Comment: What Mac?  Only knowing that can anyone tell you whether or not you can upgrade past HS.

Comment: Mac OS high Sierra.10.13.6 (17G66)iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 20112.5 GHz Intel Core 8 GB 1333 MHz  DDR3 AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB

Comment: 10.13.6 is the most recent macOS you can run.  Regarding apps, you may have more success with apps not in the Mac App Store. And for apps in the Mac App Store the developer's web site may have versions for older Macs. Apple is not very friendly for new Mac users with an old Mac.

Comment: I’ve removed the part about Time Machine as that’s a different problem that you should ask a separate question for.

Comment: ok so high Sierra is the most updated I can get.. would it be worth (or make much difference) if I added 2 x 4gb ram?

Comment: RAM might help a bit, but the real performance bottleneck on all the old iMacs is the HDD.